# No matching function

Tags: c++

I'm using a function from a header file that's pre-defined for the exercise I'm doing. In main I've got;

```
defineClickListener(clickAction, graph);
```

clickAction is a function I've made and has a prototype above main and graph is an instance of a pathfindergraph class. In pathfindergraphics header, which is included, it says;

```
/**
 * Function: defineClickListener
 * Usage: defineClickListener(clickFn);
 *        defineClickListener(clickFn, data);
 * ------------------------------------------
 * Designates a function that will be called whenever the user
 * clicks the mouse in the graphics window.  If a click listener
 * has been specified by the program, the event loop will invoke
 *
 *       clickFn(pt)
 *
 * or
 *
 *       clickFn(pt, data)
 *
 * depending on whether the data parameter is supplied.  In either
 * case, pt is the GPoint at which the click occurred and data
 * is a parameter of any type appropriate to the application.  The
 * data parameter is passed by reference, so that the click function
 * can modify the program state.
 */
void defineClickListener(void (*actionFn)(const GPoint& pt));

template <typename ClientType>
void defineClickListener(void (*actionFn)(const GPoint& pt, ClientType & data), ClientType & data);
```

As far as I can see I'm using the defineClickListener correctly, but I'm getting an error that says "no matching function for call to 'defineClickListener'". Not sure what I'm doing wrong- any ideas?

Comment: Try to call your function with `defineClickListener<Type of client>(..)`

Comment: What would the type of client be? I tried PathfinderGraph but that didnt work.

Comment: I've already used addButton("Map", mapAction, graph); which looks very similar in the header, in the same way, and it works fine...

Comment: How is `clickAction` declared? Post the full declaration. (No need to post the body, just the signature).

Comment: static void clickAction(PathfinderGraph *&graph);

Comment: What is the relation between PathfinderGraph and GPoint? As per the header the function clickAction should be taking a `cont GPoint&` as input.

Comment: If you had posted the compiler output rather than typing a snippet of the error, you'd probably have gotten your answer already. For future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the arguments you supplied cannot be matched to the parameters of the template function you are trying to call. There could be many reasons for this. Error message generated by the compiler typically includes additional information.

I would make a semi-wild guess that your `clickAction` is a non-static member function.

EDIT: According to the additional information you supplied your `clickAction` is declared as

```
static void clickAction(PathfinderGraph *&graph)
```

This is completely unacceptable. Firstly, the handler function has to have two paramaters, the first being `const GPoint&`

```
static void clickAction(const GPoint& pt, PathfinderGraph *&graph)
```

Secondly, according to the template declaration the type of the second parameter of the handler function must match the type of the last parameter of `defineClickListener`, i.e. both must be references to the same type. What is `graph` in your call to `defineClickListener`. If `graph` is a pointer to `PathfinderGraph`, then you should indeed use the above declaration.

But if `graph` is not a pointer (a reference to graph object or graph object itself), then it should be

```
static void clickAction(const GPoint& pt, PathfinderGraph &graph)
```

Comment: @Robbie Cooper: Does the signature match? I.e. is it declared to take `const GPoint&` and `const YourGraphType &` parameters?

Comment: The compiler says "candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction"

Comment: @Robbie Cooper: "failed template argument deduction" means there's something wrong with how your `clickAction` is declared. Post the declaration of `clickAction`.

Comment: If you look at "usage" in the comments above, it's telling me not to enter any arguments for GPoint, its generated when the user clicks

Comment: static void clickAction(PathfinderGraph *&graph);

Comment: @Robbie Cooper: That is your error. If you want to use the template version, you have to declare `static void clickAction(const GPoint& pt, const PathfinderGraph &graph)`

Comment: @Robbie Cooper: See the answer, please. The exact declaration for the second parameter depends on what `graph` is in your `defineClickListener(clickAction, graph)` call. What is `graph` in that context? A pointer? A reference? Graph object itself?

Comment: graph is a pointer. Thanks for pointing that out- the compiler actually accepted *& in the arguments for mapAction, and it worked fine, so I thought that was ok. Have amended both to *const &graph

Comment: Yeah, *& works, it is a pointer to an instance of pathfindergraph

Comment: @Robbie Cooper: Sorry, my insistence on `const` in the second argument was the result of my own confusion. I thought that API had `const` in the second parameter as well, but it really doesn`t.  There's no need for that `const` there. I already edited my answer to remove any references to that `const`. Just make sure you got `&` or `*&` part correctly.